# Timing etiquette of asking for update on book manuscript review

Tags: publications, publishers

I submitted a book manuscript to Springer. The editor told me that it looked great and that they would send it for peer review and would contact me in due course. But I haven’t heard of the project for 7 months. I don’t even know if it’s under peer review, since it’s not an article and therefore I don’t have the journal’s progress bar to check on. A month ago, 3 days before the six-month mark, I sent an email asking about status (because when I’ve been given a deadline to review a full book, it’s been 6 months). I received no answer. Question: is it OK if I insist with another polite email on the 7-month mark?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can ask. Ask if it is under review. Ask when you can get some feedback. Ask if there is anything you can or should do at this time.

You could even ask why it is taking so long. You should have heard *something* in seven months even if the review is taking longer than expected.

Comment: Thanks, Buffy. These things take so long that one can be at a completely different stage in their personal or work life when they get back to you. The manuscript has already changed a bit even, but I will wait to make the changes when and if they ask for edits.

Comment: I disagree with the premise that this is a long time. Six months seems to be the normal amount of time given to a referee to review a book in OP's field.

Comment: But seven is 16% more.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, no, it isn't a long time for completion, but it is a long time with no feedback at all. The editor should have better communication with an author they are considering publishing. Should and author just shut up and take it no matter what? They might have other publishing options. The author has offered something of value to the publisher. No communication is insulting.

Comment: @all Ok. I’ll write and get back to you!